# How does chaiscript handle big objects?

Tags: c++, performance, ram, large-data, chaiscript

I am considering using *chaiscript* for my project. However, I have a question about performance. Maybe it has been answered already somewhere, but I couldn't find it...

I have a simulation using large data structures (at least 1-2GB). Therefore, I fear that I will blow my RAM by doing something like this in chaiscript:

```
var data = create_big_structure();
for (var i = 1; i < max; ++i)
{
   var new_data = update_structure(i, data);
   output_data_evolution(data, new_data);
   data = new_data;
}
//data is not needed anymore
```

My questions are:

1. Will *chaiscript* delete the data between each loop execution? Namely `new_data`...
2. Will *chaiscript* delete the data after exiting loops? Again `new_data`...
3. If the answer to 1. and 2. is yes, is there another way I would need to check, to still be safe?
4. Will *chaiscript* delete unused variables? Namely `data`, after the loop... (I guess the answer is no.)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of testing, I found the answer to my questions with the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <chaiscript/chaiscript.hpp>

std::vector<int> create_big_structure() {
  //This is 1GB in size.
  return std::vector<int>(268435456);
}
std::vector<int> update_structure(int i, const std::vector<int>& data) {
  //This is 1GB in size.
  return std::vector<int>(268435456);
}
void output_data_evolution(const std::vector<int>& data, const std::vector<int>& new_data) {}

int main() {
  chaiscript::ChaiScript chai;

  chai.add(chaiscript::fun(&create_big_structure), "create_big_structure");
  chai.add(chaiscript::fun(&update_structure), "update_structure");
  chai.add(chaiscript::fun(&output_data_evolution), "output_data_evolution");
  chai.add(chaiscript::bootstrap::standard_library::vector_type<std::vector<int>>("VectorInt"));
  chai.eval(R"(
    var max = 5;
    var data = create_big_structure();
    for (var i = 1; i < max; ++i)
    {
      var new_data = update_structure(i, data);
      output_data_evolution(data, new_data);
      data = new_data;
    }
  )");
}
```

I ran the code using MSVC, and looked at the runtime statistics to figure out what happened in the RAM: [Runtime Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wMio.png)

The code works reasonably. After a startup phase, 1GB of RAM is allocated for the `data` object. In the loop, the RAM stays at 2GB, because we also have the `new_data` object. After the loop, it falls down to 1GB.

Therefore, the answers to my questions are:

1. *chaiscript* does indeed delete the data after each looping of the for statement.
2. *chaiscript* does delete the data after the loops as well.
3. Yes, you need to check that the c++ functions do not create unnecessary data. For example, if you write with a copy instead of a reference -- `update_structure(int i, std::vector<int> data)`, then the function will use a copy of data, and therefore the RAM will jump to 3GB in the loop.
4. *chaiscript* does not delete unused data inside the same block. (`new_data` is deleted after the loop, but not `data`.)

Comment: As the author of ChaiScript I will comment that yes, all objects are deleted after they leave the current scope. I think this makes ChaiScript one of the very few scripting languages where you can rely on object lifetime and have predictable destructor calls.

So in the case of your "data" object, it's effectively a global, living in the top scope, there's no way for it to get destroyed. You could put it in an explicit `{}` scope as you can with C++.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I played for a while with the idea of adding scripting support to my programme, but I did not know how to do that. I found *chaiscript* by accident, but am quite happy to see it solve my problems so easily :D